Stripe connect API - Payment intent and Account connected (where am i going wrong)
so im developping a project which is a platform between food vendor and Customers.
I am using flutterflow as a low code tool, flutter as backend code and Stripe for payments.
I am particularly using Stripe Connect API.
I would like the following:

My customer can buy a product and it creates a charge (not settling though)
until the customer go and pickup his food, and when he click complete, the charge gets triggered.
i want my platform to take an application fee (the cut on the sale) and the money to be paid directly to the vendor

#1 - is it possible?
#2 - which API to use?
i have tried to use the direct charges with session and connected account but i was not able to hold the funds until a later event
I. have tried the payment intent API but i am not sure whether it is possible to specify the seller in the payment (i dont see any thing as "connected account" in tne API documentation)

Yes that is possible, and you would want to look at the Destination Charge flow, for an Express Connected Account + Checkout for the easiest integration with Stripe Connect.
There are 2 ways of collecting fee: using application_fee_amount or transfer_data[amount] mentioned in the "Collect fees" section.
Here is a illustrative fund flow taken from the guide: 

Hello @orakaro and thanks for taking the time to answer.  I was reviewing the Documentation however when I do see the schema seems to fit my need, is it possible to hold the funds in this flow until a later time (when goods get confirmed to be delivered). For user protection I would rather that the connected account (seller) does not get funds until customer has confirmed delivery !

For card payment yes you have maximum of 7 days. See https://docs.stripe.com/payments/place-a-hold-on-a-payment-method. For other you would probably need to think of collecting their information by SetupIntent first, then charge the real amount later.
